# raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.") mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from. Error

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have had this MySQL error for quite some time now. I cant seem to understand why it keeps occurring, I have imported my database file with all the right information to make the connection but for some reason the error still occurs. I have similar functionality scattered all over my project and I have never got this error, it is literally word for word copying and yet I still get this error. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated as I have had no luck online.

Thanks.

Code:

```
def membership_reactivation(self):
    connection.connect(user="root", password="")
    email = self.EmailBox.get()
    password = self.PasswordBox.get()
    query = "UPDATE users SET Status = 'ACTIVE' WHERE Email = %s AND Password = %s;"
    cursor.execute(query, (email, password,))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
if result:
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    self.controller.show_frame("ThankYou")
else:
    print("Credentials Not Found in Database.")
    connection.close()
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AJE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\AJE\PycharmProjects\ReactivateMembership.py", line 58, in membership_reactivation
    result = cursor.fetchall()
  File "C:\Users\AJE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 1002, in fetchall
    raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
```

Comment: ``UPDATE`` statements don't have a result set.

Comment: @MikeScotty Mike, I love you. You are a legend.